# swift 3 error xcode 8.1 while assigning rootviewcontroller says it is a get-only property

Tags: swift, swift3, ios10

I was migrating my project from swift 2.2 to 3.0, when I reached a point where I get this strange error, which does not allow me to set rootviewcontroller in the app delegate didfinishlaunching. 
self.window?.rootViewController = self.container.resolve(DPSlideMenuController.self)!
[image]

Comment: The code works fine here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally fixed it. The issue was there was a var named rootViewController in one of the protocol extension.

```
var rootViewController: UIViewController {
        return (UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController)!
    }
```

Was working fine with Swift 2.2, but on swift 3 was confusing the compiler. Changed the name and the code got compiled.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you're using this library [SlideMenuControllerSwift](https://github.com/dekatotoro/SlideMenuControllerSwift) . It would be great if you show the whole code inside the `DidFinishLaunching` function.
Anyway, try to do the following :

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

// create viewController code...

let slideMenuController = SlideMenuController(mainViewController: mainViewController, leftMenuViewController: leftViewController, rightMenuViewController: rightViewController)
self.window?.rootViewController = slideMenuController
self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()    

return true
```

}

Comment: Its not about the library even this gives error -self.window?.rootViewController = UIViewController()

Comment: Can you post the code inside the `didFinishLaunching` function ?

The right way to present a rootViewController in appDelegate is :

`window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ViewController())`

Comment: It has something to do with my codebase, because I created a new project and the same line was working before adding any files, but after adding files it stops working.

Comment: @ Uday Veer Singh Patial: That contradicts your question.